# Base and height of equilateral triangle that are closest to integers

Tags: triangles, integers

I know that formula for the height of an equilateral triangle is `height = (1/2) * √3 * base`, so the height and base can never both be integers. But how could I find values that are as close as possible to integers? I happen to know that a base of 15 results in a height of 12.9903811, which is really close to 13. Is a better base that results in an even closer height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the continued fraction expansion for $\frac {\sqrt{3}}2$.  The [first $10$ convergents](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Convergents%5Bsqrt(3)%2F2,10%5D) are $$\left \{ 0, 1, \frac 6 {7}, \frac {13}{ 15},\frac  {84}{97}, \frac {181}{ 209}, \frac {1170}{1351}, \frac {2521}{ 2911}, \frac {16296}{ 18817}, \frac {35113}{ 40545}\right \} $$

Note that your $13,15$ pair occurs early on.

Using the final one, we note that $$\frac {35113}{ 40545}=0.866025403872240\dots$$ while $$\frac {\sqrt 3}2=0.86602540378443864676\dots$$ and $$40545\times \frac {\sqrt 3}2=35112.99999644\dots$$

Comment: I tried "convergents to" in Alpha and it didn't give me the list.  Thanks.

Comment: @RossMillikan  Yeah, it took me a few tries to guess the syntax, that's why I linked to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get arbitrarily close.  A good way is to look at the convergents of the [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) for $\frac {\sqrt 3}2$  In this case it is $[0;1,\overline{6,2}]$ or $$\frac 1{1+\frac 1{6+\frac 1{2+\frac 1{6+\frac 1{2+\ldots}}}}}$$
$\frac {13}{15}$ comes from taking just the first $6$ and first $2$, so
$$\frac 1{1+\frac 1{6+\frac 12}}=\frac 1{1+\frac 2{13}}=\frac{13}{15}$$  They are particularly close if you stop before a large term, so you could next look at 
$$\frac 1{2+\frac 1{6+\frac 12}}=\frac 1{2+\frac 2{13}}=\frac{13}{28}\\
\frac 1{1+\frac 1{6+\frac {13}{28}}}=\frac 1{1+\frac {28}{181}}=\frac {181}{209}\\
\left(\frac{181}{209}\right)^2\approx 0.7500057$$